# Why $\{e\} \ast_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, limits-colimits

Am I correct?
Following Serre's "Trees", I can conclude that
$\{e\}\ast_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} = \varinjlim (\{e\},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ with respect to homomorphisms:

a)  $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto e$,

ii) $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $a \mapsto -a$,

в) $e \mapsto 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So we have 
$\varinjlim (\{e\},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) = (\{e\} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z})/\langle(e,a,0)\equiv(e,0,0), (e,0,b) \equiv (e,0,-b) \rangle_{a,b \in \mathbb{Z}}$ which is obviously $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: I can't get some of your symbols. :-(

Comment: @mrs What do you mean?

Comment: I meant, that $\lim_{\to}$

Comment: @NicholasS Without a copy of Serre's book to hand, the notation is rather cryptic.

Comment: @mrs It's an injective limit. You can read more about it in Atiyah-Macdonald, chapter 2.

Comment: @NicholasS: Oh thanks, I see

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don’t understand what you mean. I used standard algebraic notations.

Comment: No, it's cryptic. Are you working in the category of groups? if so $\oplus$ has little categorical meaning. Also, there are two $\mathbb{Z}$ in the data, and it's not always clear which occurrence of $\mathbb{Z}$ is what. Also, your enumeration a) ii) b) is clumsy. Also, "$\mathbb{Z}\mapsto e$" is weird; $\mapsto$ should be surrounded by elements. I'm not really sure what your diagram is: from the initial amalgam notation, it looks like $\{e\}\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, but you refer to a homomorphism $\{e\}\to\mathbb{Z}$. To conclude, it's hard to make any sense without more efforts.

Comment: @YCor You're right. My professor explained the mistake. I can't compute the direct limit as I did here, because the amalgam usually is not an abelian group (I actually used the definition of direct limit for modules over commutative ring). The crucial here is the definition of morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. Cutting out the strip from the Moebius band, we obtain the doubled ring. So the morphism should be given by $n \mapsto 2n$.